# Get correct values from Mysql database using dynamically created text boxes PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

In my application just I am trying to get `data` from `MYSQL` database and set into `text_name` and `amount` `text boxes` by dynamically created text boxes.

As I first dynamically created `text box`, it retrieve the `data` according to the `Test_ID (test_id text box)` is correctly work, but in the next dynamically created `text box`, just it does not show the `data` according to the `Test_ID`, but in console it retrieve the data according to the previously added `Test_ID`, does not `fetch` the `data` of currently added

Here the `HTML` code

```
<table class="table table-hover table-white">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-1">Test ID</th>
        <th class="col-md-6">Test Name</th>
        <th style="width:100px;">Amount</th>
        <th> Action</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="rows">
     <tr>
        <td> <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width:200px" id="test_id[]" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();">
        </td>
        <td> <input  type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control"  readonly="" id="test_name"  onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();">
        </td>
        <td> <input  type="text" style="min-width:100px" class="form-control" readonly="" id="amount">
        </td>
        <td><center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-success font-18" title="Add" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> </center> </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the `Ajax` code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        
    var count=0;
    $(document).on('click','#add',function() {
    count++; 
    
    var html= '';
    html += '<tr id="trrows">';
    
    html += '<td id="testid"> <input id="test_id[]" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:200px" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"> </td>';
    html += '<td id="testname"> <input id="test_name"  type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control "  readonly="" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"> </td>';
    html += '<td id="amounts">  <input id="amount" type="text" style="min-width:150px" class="form-control"  readonly="" > </td>';
    html += '<td><center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-danger font-18 remove" title="Remove" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></center> </td>';
    
    html +=  '</tr>';
    
    $('#rows').append(html);
    
    });
    
    $(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
    $(this).closest("#trrows").remove();
    });
    
    
    });
    
// fetch test name from database      
    function checkname()
    {
    
    var test_id = document.getElementById("test_id[]").value;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "adminquery/fetch_test_name.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
        data: {'test_id': test_id,},
    success: function (data) {
      $("#test_name").val(data);
        }
       });
    
    // fetch amount from database    
    var testid = document.getElementById("test_id[]").value;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "adminquery/fetch_test_name.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
        data: {'testid': testid, },
    success: function (data) {
    $("#amount").val(data);
    
    }
    });
             
    }
```

Really I am appreciating if someone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are getting value of the element using `id` which will give you first input value with same id .Instead while append new pass `this` inside function which will refer to current element which is changed .

So , change your **jquery** code like below :

```
    $(document).on('click','#add',function() {
       //other codes
       //add this inside function
        html += '<td id="testid"> <input id="test_id[]" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:200px"  onchange="checkname(this);"> </td>';
     //add class
      html += '<td id="testname"> <input id="test_name" class="test_name" type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control "  readonly="" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"> </td>';
   
       // other code
      });  

 function checkname(el)
    {  
    var test_id = $(el).val();//get that value  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "adminquery/fetch_test_name.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
        data: {'test_id': test_id,},
    success: function (data) {
     //get closest tr and find class with .test_name 
      $(el).closest('tr').find('.test_name').val(data);
        }
       });
    //same do for other
     }
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var count = 0;
  $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
    count++;

    var html = '';
    html += '<tr id="trrows">';

    html += '<td id="testid"> <input id="test_id[]" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:200px" onchange="checkname(this);"> </td>';
    html += '<td id="testname"> <input id="test_name"  type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control test_name"  readonly="" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"> </td>';
    html += '<td id="amounts">  <input id="amount" type="text" style="min-width:150px" class="form-control"  readonly="" > </td>';
    html += '<td><center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-danger font-18 remove" title="Remove" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o">-</i></a></center> </td>';

    html += '</tr>';

    $('#rows').append(html);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest("#trrows").remove();
  });


});

// fetch test name from database      
function checkname(el) {

  var test_id = $(el).val();
  console.log(test_id)
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "adminquery/fetch_test_name.php", 
    data: {
      'test_id': test_id,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //get closest tr and find test_name class
      $(el).closest('tr').find('.test_name').val(data);
    }
  });

  //do same for othere input..

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-white">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-sm-1">Test ID</th>
      <th class="col-md-6">Test Name</th>
      <th style="width:100px;">Amount</th>
      <th> Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="rows">
    <tr>
      <td> <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width:200px" id="test_id[]" onchange="checkname(this);">
      </td>
      <!--add class here-->
      <td> <input type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control" class="test_name" readonly="" id="test_name" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();">
      </td>
      <td> <input type="text" style="min-width:100px" class="form-control" readonly="" id="amount">
      </td>
      <td>
        <center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-success font-18" title="Add" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus">+</i></a> </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```